# Opening a specific folder using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, path

I am trying to create a workspace in Visual Studio Code using PowerShell. However, the `code .` command is not working the way I need it to. I have created a path variable in the following location: AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin. However, this only works when `code .` is the first command I run which opens a huge workspace. When I try to `cd` into specific folders and then use the `code .` command I get an error that says the system cannot find the path specified.

[image: Example of error]

Comment: what is the section in your `$env:Path` that has the VSCode path in it? the path you show is not likely to work since i lacks a drive/volume starting point.

Comment: Run `Get-Command code | Format-Table -AutoSize` from directory where `code .` fails as well as `$env:Path -split ';' | ForEach-Object { "[$_]" }` and compare output.

Comment: Note that the error message is the standard Windows system error message for error code `3`, indicating that a _directory_ could not be found, such as when using `cd` from `cmd.exe` (in a batch file) with a nonexistent directory path, it does _not_ indicate the inability find a `code` command (which should be a `*.cmd` file with contents that wouldn't produce this error).

Comment: @Lee_Dailey How do I check that? I am new to all of this and not sure what you mean

Comment: @RCE11 - the comment by `JosefZ` shows how to find those values. on my system, the path statement has `C:\Users\[MyUsername]\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin` at the end. i confirmed that there is a `.CMD` file there that starts `code.exe` with some extra stuff.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey when I try to run Get-Command code | Format-Table - AutoSize I get an error that says, "'Get-Command' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: @RCE11 - the `Get-Command` cmdlet is a _basic_ cmdlet. if you cannot run that, then you are not running a fully functional install of powershell. can you run `get-help get-com`, then tab complete the text, and hit enter to run the help command?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey ok Get-Command give me this, "**Application code.cmd 0.0.0.0 AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code.cmd**" and the other command gives me, "**[AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin]
[AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin]**"

Comment: @Lee_Dailey sorry not sure why I could not get it to work earlier.

Comment: @RCE11 - the `appdata` should be preceded by your user directory. mine starts with `c:\users\[myusername]\` and then the appdata stuff. it appears that your installation is damaged. you likely should REMOVE the info from your path, and then rerun the install of VSCode & let it repair things.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I uninstalled VSCode and removed the path variable and upon re downloading and restarting, it now works! Thank you for your help!

Comment: @RCE11 - you are most welcome ... glad to have helped a tad! [*grin*]